# I have a problem with the state.map in react.js not showing data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having a problem with my code. I'm fetching data from the server-side (node.js) and save it in using setState(data), when I do the console.log(this.state.data) it Shows all the data, but When I try to do the map it returns nothing.

Although, when I create an object on the CardList.js it shows the data correctly.

CardList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './card';
import {getAllData} from '../store/store';
import '../sass/cardList.scss';


class CardsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

 async updateState() {
   var datas = await getAllData();
   this.setState({data: datas});
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.updateState();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    const cards = this.state.data.map(([key, element]) => <Card key={key} title={element.title} url={element.url} target={element.target} category={element.category} date={element.date}/>) 
    return(
          <div className="cardList">
            {cards}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
  export default CardsList;
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../sass/card.scss';

class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="card-container">
          <div>
          <a href={this.props.url} target={this.props.target}><span className="category font">{this.props.category}</span> <span className="font">{this.props.date}</span></a>
          </div>
          <div>
          <h3 className="title">{this.props.title}</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
          <p className="small">{this.props.url}</p>
          </div> 
        </div>
      ) 
    }
  }

  export default Card;
```

store.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/'
})
export  function getAllData(){
    var data = [];
    api.get('/')
    .then((response) =>{
       response.data.forEach((item) => {
         data.push(item);
       });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       return console.log(error);
    });
    return data;
}

export function getDataByCategory(category){
  var data = [];
   api.get('/'+category).then(response => {
    response.data.forEach((item) => {
      data.push(item);
    });
      }).catch((err) => {
       return console.log(err);
      });
    return data;
}


export  function getMenu(){
  var data = [];
  api.get('/menu')
  .then((response) =>{
     response.data.forEach((item) => {
       data.push(item);
     });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     return console.log(error);
  });
  return data;
}
```

Server-Side:
routes.js

```
const appRouter = (app, fs) => {
    //variables
    const data =  './data/globalSearch.json';

    app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
        fs.readFile(data, 'utf8',(err, data) => {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.send(200,JSON.parse(data).posts);
        })
    }),
    app.get('/menu', (req, res) => {
        fs.readFile(data,'utf8', (err, data) => {
            res.send(JSON.parse(data).menu);
        })
    }),
    app.get("/:category", (req, res) => {
        const category = req.params.category;
        var postsFound = [];
        console.log("category: ", category);
        fs.readFile(data,'utf8', (err, data) => {
            const posts = JSON.parse(data).posts
            postsFound = posts.map( post => {if(post.category == category) return post}).filter(value => value != null); 
            res.send(postsFound);
        })
    })
};

module.exports = appRouter;
```

This is the output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmhLw.png

If I create the default data in the CardsList, the cards appear witht the info
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emse9.png

Answer (score 0):

see if this works:

```
render() {

    return(
          <div className="cardList">
            {this.state.data.length!==0?this.state.data.map((key, element) => return (<Card key={key} title={element.title} url={element.url} target={element.target} category={element.category} date={element.date}/>);):' ' }
          </div>
      );
  }
```

Sorry if any typos.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still not working :(

Comment: What output you are getting on your screen?

Comment: It doesn't show the cards with the info. But if I go to the console, you can see all the data.
However, If i create the same object here in the CardsList, and if I do the map... it works... But I want to show the cards it the info from the server side.

Comment: you can see the outputs images, I added to the questions

Comment: okay try removing return from `return (<Card key={key} title={element.title} url={element.url} target={element.target} category={element.category} date={element.date}/>);)`

Comment: i have edited my answer,try the new approach.

Comment: I did Like you said in your answer, but still nothing.

Comment: did you try by removing return ?

Comment: can you paste your Card component's code?

Comment: Yes, i try removing return, nothing, try your answer, nothing.

You have the Card.js file in the code to. the cardList will do the loop to create the card component.

Comment: may be what you can do is pass the whole data to your Card component and display there your data by mapping

Comment: ideally that should at least :D